# I need to count n-gram frequency

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have list of tweets and i need to know the n-gram for two words
first i am convert list to str like

```
text_ = str(list_)
```

then the text will be like

```
'Based today data dshs website almost vaccine received unused At current vaccination rate take entire st qtr get group done And gets harder What say ye COVID vaccine' 'That thing About teachers incl staff At least cohorts students groups attend classes together day quarantined home given time past months It catch vaccine'
```

and import the Libraries

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import ngrams
```

then applied my code

```
n_gram = 2

terms = Counter(ngrams(text_.split(), n_gram))
```

and i get [image]

the final result i want should be like
for example

```
[(('based', 'today'), 2),
 (('vaccine ', 'recived'), 2),
 (('attend ', 'happening'), 1),
 (('that', 'the'), 1)]
```

any helping very appreciated
best regards

Comment: Show input text and desired output

Comment: i convert my list to str and the input its like `'Based today data dshs website almost vaccine received unused At current vaccination rate take entire st qtr get group done And gets harder What say ye COVID vaccine' 'That thing About teachers incl staff At least cohorts students groups attend classes together day quarantined home given time past months It catch vaccine'` and the result stay same

Comment: Please update your question with input text and desired output. Please do not use comments to provide additional useful info. Include into the body of your post instead

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have list of text strings (tweets):

```
texts = ('Based today data dshs website almost vaccine received unused '
        'At current vaccination rate take entire st qtr get group done ' 
        'And gets harder What say ye COVID vaccine',
        'That thing About teachers incl staff At least cohorts students '
        ' groups attend classes together day quarantined home given '
        'time past months It catch vaccine')
```

Then you may proceed for uni-, bi-, and tri-grams like following:

```
for text in texts:
    unigrams = text.split()
    unigram_counts = {}
    for unigram in unigrams:
        unigram_counts[unigram] = unigram_counts.get(unigram, 0) +1

    bigrams = [",".join(bigram) for bigram in zip(unigrams[:-1], unigrams[1:])]
    bigram_counts = {}
    for bigram in bigrams:
        bigram_counts[bigram] = bigram_counts.get(bigram, 0) +1

    trigrams = [",".join(trigram) for trigram in zip(unigrams[:-2], unigrams[1:-1],unigrams[2:])]
    trigram_counts = {}
    for trigram in trigrams:
        trigram_counts[trigram] = trigram_counts.get(trigram, 0) +1

    print(bigram_counts)
```

---

```
{'That,thing': 1, 'thing,About': 1, 'About,teachers': 1, ...
```

Should you wish to have sorted by frequency list of tuples, you may proceed as follows:

```
list_of_tuples = [(tuple(key.split(',')),value) for key,value in bigram_counts.items()]
sorted(list_of_tuples,key=lambda x:-x[1])
```

Comment: @Ibrahim Did it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.